# What do chi ($χ$), psi ($ψ$), and capital gamma ($Γ$) stand for in these equations about molecular geometry (combination bands and overtones)?

Tags: wavefunction, notation, physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, quantum-chemistry

> #### Special case
>
> If one of the symmetries is doubly degenerate in the excited state a recursion formula is required to determine the symmetry of the $v$<sup>th</sup> wave function, given by,
>
> $$\chi _{v}(R) = \frac{1}{2} \left [\chi (R) \chi_{v-1}(R) + \chi (R^{v}) \right]\tag5$$
>
> Where $\chi _{v}(R)$ is the character under the operation $R$ for the $v$<sup>th</sup> energy level; $\chi (R)$ is the character under $R$ for the degenerate irreducible representation; $\chi_{v-1}(R)$ is the character of the $(v-1)$th energy level; and $\chi (R^{v})$ is the character of the operation $R^v$. This is demonstrated for the $D_{3h}$ point group below.

> #### Combination Bands
>
> Combination bands are observed when more than two or more fundamental vibrations are excited simultaneously. One reason a combination band might occur is if a fundamental vibration does not occur because of symmetry. This is comparable to vibronic coupling in electronic transitions in which a fundamental mode can be excited and allowed as a “doubly excited state.” Combination implies addition of two frequencies, but it also possible to have a difference band where the frequencies are subtracted.
>
> To determine if two states can be excited simultaneous the transition moment integral must be evaluated with the appropriate excited state wavefunction. For example, in the transition,
>
> $$\psi ^{_{1}}\left( 0 \right )\psi ^{_{2}}\left ( 0 \right )\psi ^{_{3}}\left ( 0 \right )\rightarrow \psi ^{_{1}}\left ( 2 \right )\psi ^{_{2}}\left ( 0 \right )\psi ^{_{3}}\left ( 1 \right )\tag6$$
>
> the symmetry of the excited state will be the direct product of the irreducible representation for $\psi_1(2)$ and $\psi_3(1)$.
>
> For example, in the point group $C_{4v}$, $v_1$ has symmetry $e$ and $v_3$ has symmetry $a_2$. By performing the calculations listed above, it is determined that $\psi_1(2)$ has $(a_1 + b_1 + b_2)$ symmetry:
>
> $$\Gamma [\psi_{es}] = \Gamma [\psi _{1}(2)] \otimes \Gamma [\psi _{3}(1)] = (a_{1} + b_{1} + b_{2})\times a_{2} = a_{2} + b_{2} + b_{1}\tag7$$

([Source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Spectroscopy/Vibrational_Modes/Combination_Bands%2C_Overtones_and_Fermi_Resonances))

Also, what does $\psi_{es}$ mean?  What is $es$?

Comment: Which reference? Which page?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!